# procedure upgrading commission_pct of every employee where department_id = 80

Tags: plsql

am trying to write a procedure that upgrades commission_pct for every employees in department 80 , new commission_pct is (number of year worked/10)*0.5.
there is my code . my question is how to add this new commission_pct to the code and call the procedure . thanks

```
PROCEDURE increase_comm(department_id NUMBER, comm_incr NUMBER) IS 
    curr_comm NUMBER; 
BEGIN 
  SELECT commission_pct 
  INTO curr_comm 
  FROM employees 
  WHERE employees.department_id = increase_comm.department_id; 
  IF curr_comm IS NULL 
     THEN RAISE no_comm; 
  ELSE 
     UPDATE employees 
     SET commission_pct = commission_pct + comm_incr; 
  END IF; 
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You explained your problem in very confusing way, but if I am right,
and assuming that comm_incr is this 0.5 value then:

```
PROCEDURE increase_comm(deptno NUMBER, comm_incr NUMBER) IS 
    curr_comm NUMBER; 
BEGIN 
  SELECT commission_pct 
  INTO curr_comm 
  FROM employees 
  WHERE department_id = deptno;
  IF curr_comm IS NULL 
     THEN RAISE no_comm; 
  ELSE 
     UPDATE employees 
     SET commission_pct = curr_comm * comm_incr; 
  END IF; 
END;
```

Procedure you can execute like this:

```
begin
 execute increase_comm(80,0.5);
 end;
```